# How to alternate between children/data of two firebase references in the same recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I have two firebase references, the Events reference for storing posted events and another one is the Ads reference for ads created by people on premium. I want to display one Advert from Ads reference every after 3 events in my recycler view, and am wondering how this can be achieved. So far I can display all events by the help of firebase recycler adapter and I don't know how i can include Adverts as well on the same page/activity.
Below is the code I have managed to write so far to display the events and it works fine.

```
protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<EventModel> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<EventModel>()
                .setQuery(event_reference,EventModel.class).build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<EventModel, EventViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<EventModel, EventViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EventViewHolder eventViewHolder, int i, @NonNull final EventModel events) {
                StringBuilder date_time = new StringBuilder()
                        .append(events.getEventDate())
                        .append(": ")
                        .append(events.getEventTime());
                eventViewHolder.eventName.setText(events.getEventName());
                eventViewHolder.eventDate.setText(date_time);
                eventViewHolder.eventVenue.setText(events.getEventVenue());
                Glide.with(HomeActivity.this)
                        .load(events.getEventPoster())
                        .into(eventViewHolder.eventPoster);
                user_reference.child(events.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if(snapshot.child("avatar").exists()){
                            Glide.with(HomeActivity.this)
                                    .load(snapshot.child("avatar").getValue())
                                    .into(eventViewHolder.eventOwnerAvatar);
                        }else{
                            Glide.with(HomeActivity.this)
                                    .load(R.drawable.avatar)
                                    .into(eventViewHolder.eventOwnerAvatar);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
                Log.d("name", events.getEventName());
                Log.d("date", events.getEventDate());
                Log.d("venue", events.getEventVenue());

                eventViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                            Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, EventDetailsActivity.class);
                            i.putExtra("eventRandomKey",events.getEventRandomKey());
                            startActivity(i);

                    }
                });


            }

            @Override
            public void onDataChanged(){
//                if(mProgress_bar!=null){
//                    mProgress_bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
//                }
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
                public EventViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.event_cards,parent,false);
                EventViewHolder holder = new EventViewHolder(view);
                return holder;
            }
        };
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }
```

But I failed to display one Advert from Ads reference every after 3 events that come from the Events reference in my recycler view or same page/activity.
Your help will save me a lot. Thanks

Comment: Can you please include the code you've attempted and kind of difficulty you're having? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Kindly check, I have editted my question...